# What does "a smaller number of people" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I understand every word in this sentence but I can't understand why the author wrote so. Can anybody explain it for me, please, maybe in terms of economics or something like that?

"Debt is a major risk for countries with aging populations, particularly once working age populations start to decline, **as the debt burden will need to be financed by a smaller number of people**," he said.

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/04/19/emerging-asia-risks-growing-old-before-becoming-rich.html

Comment: What do you think the writer should've used instead? It's hard to get to the heart of your question.

Comment: When the number of workers in the working population (as distinct from the retired population) declines, the debt burden each working person bears increases.  {Debt Service}  divided by {number of people in the working population} yields the individual worker's burden of the debt financing, *ceteris paribus*.   If there are 100 workers, each worker has 1% of the debt. If there are only 50 workers, each has 2% of the debt, all things being equal.  It seems to me your question is not about language but about the economic concept.  At some point, the working population can become so small ...

Comment: ... that the burden on the individual becomes too heavy.   Large swings in population (i.e. "baby booms") can place a heavy burden on smaller working populations that follow after them when the "boomers" reach retirement age and tend to earn less and so cede much of the debt burden they bore to younger generations.

Comment: Thanks, @Tᴚoɯɐuo. That's what I need. And I wonder why the author didn't write like this: "...as the debt burden will be placed on a smaller number of people".

Comment: @haile Because the author wanted to state that the smaller number of people will be tasked with **paying back the debt** (hence "financed").

Comment: @haile: If you question concerned the verb **finance** why did you make its title "What does 'a smaller number of people' mean?"  The verb means **finance** means to borrow money to pay for something, and usually to pay interest on the amount borrowed.

Comment: No, @Tᴚoɯɐuo. I just try to rephrase it.

Comment: Well, the author was talking about the original debt and the money borrowed to pay off older debts. There is debt upon debt upon debt.

Comment: But you know, @SteveES, in my mother tongue, it should be like what I already tried to rephrase, which means it's the smaller number of people who will have to pay the debt left by the older generation.

Comment: @SteveES: "...to be placed on the shoulders of the smaller number....", to be more exact.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments point out, the meaning of "a smaller number of people" is pretty straightforward, as it simply means "fewer people".

The real question is rather what happens to those people, or why the author chose to use the word "financed".  "Debt burden" is, in itself, a "set" idiomatic expression:

> [Debt burden](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/debt-burden) n: the amount of debt that a particular country etc has, considered as a burden on its economy and people and a hindrance to their progress (Collins dictionary)

However it *sounds* like a metaphor, in which case "financed" should be replaced by some verb that more closely relates with the image of a "burden", such as "to bear" or "to carry" or "to reduce".  Examples:

> the debt burden must be borne by a smaller number of people
>
> the debt burden must be carried by a smaller number of people.
>
> the debt burden must be reduced by a smaller number of people.

All of these make sense *metaphorically*, whereas the verb "to finance" requires additional understanding not included in the sentence itself.  A "debt burden" is usually not paid off all at once but rather *financed* over time through interest payments -- which must be paid by *fewer earners* as the workforce ages.

Comment: In this context, it means "a smaller number of working-age people."  Depending on whether the country encourages young people to go to college, and depending on the country's typical retirement age, "working-age" could mean anything from "16-65 years old" to "25-55 years old".